# how to get socketid in socket.io(nodejs)

Tags: express, socket.io

In my nodejs application, i am using socket.io for sockets connection.

I am configuring my server side code like this

socket.io configuration in separate file.

```
//socket_io.js

var socket_io = require('socket.io');
var io = socket_io();
var socketApi = {};

socketApi.io = io;

module.exports = socketApi;
```

below is my `server.js` file in which i am attaching my socket io to the server like this

```
var socketApi = require('./server/socket_io');


// Create HTTP server.
const server = http.createServer(app);

// Attach Socket IO
var io = socketApi.io;
io.attach(server);


// Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`API running on localhost:${port}`));
```

and then i am using socket.io in my `game.js` file to emit updated user coins like this.

```
 //game.js

 var socketIO = require('../socket_io');

 function updateUserCoins(userBet) {
    userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userBet.user);

    User.findUserWithId(userId).then((user) => {
        user.coins = user.coins - userBet.betAmount;

        user.save((err, updatedUser) => {
            socketIO.io.sockets.emit('user coins', {
                userCoins: updatedUser.coins,
            });
        });

    })
}
```

and then in my client side, i am doing something like this,

```
socket.on('user coins', (data) => {
  this.coins = data.userCoins;
});
```

but with the above implementation, updating coins of any user, updates all user coins at the client side, since all the clients are listening to the same socket `user coins`.

To solve the above problem, i know that i have to do something like this,

```
// sending to individual socketid (private message)
socketIO.io.sockets.to(<socketid>).emit('user coins', {
    userCoins: updatedUser.coins,
});
```

but my concern is that how will get `<socketid>` with my current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by listening to connection to your socket.io server :

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
   socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
   socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
   });
});
```

Here you have a socket object ( `io.on('connection', function (socket)` ) and you can get his id with `socket.id`

So you'll probably need to wrap your code with the connection listener.

[Source of the exemple for the connection listener](https://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4)

[Socket object description](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket)